# fxml include other fxml files and user defined property

Tags: javafx, scenebuilder

Hy,

I have following question.

Is it possible to create a main fxml file and place/include a other fxml file which  should have a user defined property.

For example I have  : `main.fxml` and a `fan_object.fxml` 
 Then include 3 `fan_object.fxml` onto the `main.fxml`. And now i want to define for each `fan_object.fxml` instance a other address or tooltip text and so on?

is this possible?

Comment: Welcome to SO. What is your goal ? have afxml menu and switch content inside ?

Answer (score 6):

Check in the documentation : [fx:include](https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/fxml/doc-files/introduction_to_fxml.html#include_elements)

What you can do is the following :

If this is your **main.fxml**

```
<?import javafx.scene.control.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>
<VBox xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml">
    <children>
        <fx:include fx:id="fan1" source="fan_object.fxml"/>
        <fx:include fx:id="fan2" source="fan_object.fxml"/>
        <fx:include fx:id="fan3" source="fan_object.fxml"/>
    </children>
</VBox>
```

In your **MainController.java** class :

```
@FXML
private FanController fan1Controller;
@FXML
private FanController fan2Controller;
@FXML
private FanController fan3Controller;
```

Now in your **FanController.java** class :

```
public void setToolTip (String tooltipText){
        //You put the tooltip of the object you have in this controller
        //for instance
        myButton.setTooltip(new Tooltip(tooltipText));
}
```

Now all you have to do is call :

```
fan1Controller.setToolTip("Tip : !");
```

Hope this deals with your question.

Comment: @charlesLgn  You are right, but since there is no code presented, I thought this is more of "you need more documentation" thing, if you see what I mean. I will edit it gradually though. vague answer for vague question.

Comment: Thanks for your example. I take a long time to get my code work. The problem was i set the fx:id to fan1 and than i wrote `@FXML private Fancontroller fan1;`. But it should be `@FXML private Fancontroller fan1Controller`. From my point of view this is not intuitive. Thank you for your support

Comment: @MichaelSchmit No problem :D If you think my answer is good enough, please validate it with a tick :)